# MS Excel. Remove part of formula which varies throughout a range of cells

Tags: excel, function, replace, find, formula

I had this problem: I wanted to delete part of formula which varied across a range of cells (`E12, E13, E14, ..`) so I wasn't able to use "Find and replace". Specifically, I wanted to delete the second `VLOOKUP` function from the formula below and replace "Month7-15" with "Month6-15":

Formula to edit:

```
= IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E12, 'Month7-15'!$A$5:$B$353, 2, FALSE) - VLOOKUP(E12, 'Month7-15'!$A$5:$B$353, 3, FALSE), "no data")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Same guy as above**

1. Firstly, in the initial Excel workbook, I hit Ctrl + H on the selected column (same applies to row) and replaced "Month7-15" with "Month6-15"
2. Secondly, with the column selected, I hit Ctrl + Tilde, copied and paste the formulas in Notepadd++
3. Thirdly, in Notepad++, i found and replaced "=" with "", so I won't have any equal signs and copied the results to a new Excel workbook.
4. Next, in this Excel workbook I used REPLACE function and declared its parameters such as my second `VLOOKUP`function will be deleted. Because my range of cells was so big, this `REPLACE` didn't work after index exceeded row 100 - so, I had `FALSEE` instead of `FALSE`. I solved this in the next point.
5. From Excel, I copied the edited quasi-functions, pasted them in Notepad++. I introduced the equal sign by find and replace: "IFERR" with "= IFERR". I solved the issue of `FALSEE` by find and replace to `FALSE`
6. Lastly, I copied the functions from Notepad++ to the initial Excel workbook and it saved me hours of work of replacing manually the undesired part of formula in the function.

*NB.* I couldn't just use one formula to drag it down as many rows I had because I had different references as well as hard-coded values for some rows.

Hope this helps people.